Force variables in mixed-models LASSO - glmmLASSO
I want to perform feature selection in mixed models using the LASSO model implemented in the R package glmmLASSO, and I was wondering if variables can be forced to be included in the models, used as adjustment variables.
I know that for 'traditional regression' models this option is available in the function cv.glmnet of the R package glmnet, using the parameter penalty.factors, but I can't find that option in this case.
I would be very grateful if you could help me.
Thank you!
I looked in the documentation of the R package glmmLASSO, but I couldn't find anything similar.

Perhpss the third example in the help pages of ?glmmLasso can help (the one starting "linear mixed model with slope on ave.attend;  the coefficient of ave.attend is not penalized;", and from  ?glmmLassoControl, index: "Non-penalized coefficients are marked with NA".
